# Pulling single object out of SpringFramework Ehcache list

Tags: java, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-cache

Using the org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager & assuming I have the method:

```
@Cacheable("imageData") // add key = xyz here?
public List<ImageData> getProductIdAndColorCodeForSkus(List<Integer> skus) {
    thread sleep
    ...do some stuff...
    return listOfImageData;
}
```

And I have already hit this method with the skus {111111, 111222}. I would later like to pull an ImageData object out of the cache, for example:

```
Cache imageDataCache = cacheManager.getCache("imageData");
imageDataCache.get(key, ImageData.class) // what do I use for key?
```

I have tried

```
new Integer(111111)
```

but this will return back a null result. I have also tried a passing in a list with that sku as well.

Also, I know that both ImageData(s) are cached and can be retrieved individually because when I call this method a second time with a list having a single sku: 111111 or 111222 the thread sleep doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache abstraction uses `SimpleKeyGenerator` by default to generate the key based on method arguments. In your case you have a `List<Integer>` so that's going to create a `SimpleKey` with the list.

If you're not happy with that, you can customize the `KeyGenerator`. Since you are accessing the cache directly somewhere else, I would *strongly* recommend you to take control on the key generator so that your API is consistent.

More info [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key)